# GNU make many output files from single dependency which might match others

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I tried looking for answers to this question, so I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate of a question I didn't find. Also sorry that I cannot directly provide the code that I am working with (it would require a lot of environmental dependencies, anyway).

I have a sequence of actions, which all depend on the success of the previous actions, and also don't need to be repeated unless they are out of date. A `make` solution seemed like the proper one. I've come up with a solution that does *almost* all of it. Here is the sequence of steps I am trying to replicate, with the output of each step listed below its input:

- ZIP file

  - extract to `package/`
- `package/directory/*.comp`

  - execute `uncomp.py` to create a `.uncomp` file from a `.comp` file
- *Everything works fine up to this point*
- `package/directory/*.uncomp`

  - For `*.uncomp` files, execute `script1` to produce a `.html` file
  - For `*_ext.uncomp` files, execute `script2` to produce numbered `*_ext.##.png` file(s)

    - Multiple numbered files (`_ext.0.png`, `_ext.1.png`, `_ext.2.png`) are possible, and may not be present at the time `make` is run. However, `make` should know that they are the output of the previous step, and only run *this* recipe if these files (a) don't exist or (b) any are older than the `*_ext.uncomp` file.

I have put together a Makefile which does *almost* what I'm looking for, except that it delegates all of the last portion (numbered files) to a shell script which I *could* program to look at file times, but that defeats the purpose of using `make` in the first place, in my opinion.

## Environment

Debian 8.8 (x86)

```
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

## My Question

What rules and recipes can I use to inform GNU make of the relationship between the `*_ext.uncomp` files and the `_ext.##.png` files so that those recipes only get executed as necessary (and say 'Target is up-to-date' if all `.png` files are at least as new as the `_ext.uncomp` file), that won't also apply to the `*.uncomp` files, and that will still work of there are no `.png` files in the output?

I will also need to indicate the relationship between *non*-`_ext` files and their corresponding HTML counterparts. So that `script1` only gets executed when the HTML file is out of date or doesn't exist. This recipe/rule should not pay attention to `_ext.uncomp` files.

Any other advice on my Makefile would also be appreciated, because I am not overly familiar with it.

## Generalized contents of my current `Makefile`

```
.PHONY : all
all : package package/directory/*.uncomp
    ./process $^

%.comp.uncomp : %.comp package
    python uncomp.py $<

package : *.zip
    rm -rf package/
    unzip *.zip -d package/
```

## Contents of the `process` script

This script should no longer exist if all the goals of the question are met (`make` will handle everything). It works great, but it always processes `.uncomp` files no matter what, even if the output from them already exists and is newer than the source.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "$0 expects at least 2 arguments"
    exit 1
fi

# Discard the first agrument, it's always 'package'
shift

# Iterate over each of the remaining arguments
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    if [[ $1 == *_ext.uncomp ]] ; then
        python script2 $1
    elif [[ $1 == *.uncomp ]] ; then
        python script1 $1
    else
        echo "Warning: Unknown file type: $1"
    fi
    shift
done
```

Comment: I think [order only](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) prerequisites might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned a lot about GNU `make` trying to get this to work. I discovered that the solution to my problem was in not overthinking it.

The most important realization was that I didn't need `make` to track *all* of the numbered output files, but just the first one (if the first one is out of date or missing, they all will be, and they all get re-extracted by the script, so a 1:1 relationship was all I needed to indicate there).

I found out that GNU `make` 3.82 and later uses "shortest stem first" order instead of definition order when matching pattern rules. To make my file compatible with both versions, I made sure to define the most specific stems first.

After that it was a matter of setting up some implicit rules, and just telling `make` what to expect to be able to find—the concept is a little backwards to my way of thinking which is why I had some trouble at first (look for this file that doesn't exist yet; now, here's a way to make it from a file that *does* exist). The end result, fully functional:

```
PACKAGE      := package
COMP         := .comp
UNCOMP       := .comp.uncomp
PNG0         := .comp.0.png
TXT          := .comp.txt
SUFFIX       := _ext

COMPFILES     = $(wildcard $(PACKAGE)/subdir/*$(COMP))
UNCOMPFILES   = $(COMPFILES:$(COMP)=$(UNCOMP))
SUFFIXFILES   = $(filter %$(SUFFIX)$(UNCOMP),$(UNCOMPFILES))
PNGFILES      = $(SUFFIXFILES:$(UNCOMP)=$(PNG0))
NOSUFFIXFILES = $(filter-out %$(SUFFIX)$(UNCOMP),$(UNCOMPFILES))
TXTFILES      = $(NOSUFFIXFILES:$(UNCOMP)=$(TXT))

.PHONY : all
all : pngs txts htaccess

.PHONY : txts
txts : $(TXTFILES)

.PHONY : pngs
pngs : $(PNGFILES)

.PHONY : uncomp
uncomp : $(UNCOMPFILES)
    make pngs
    make txts

.PHONY : htaccess
htaccess : $(PACKAGE)/.htaccess

%$(SUFFIX)$(PNG0) : %$(SUFFIX)$(UNCOMP)
    @# Ignore failures when extracting PNG files
    -python script1.py $<

%$(TXT) : %$(UNCOMP)
    @# Ignore failures when dumping TXT files
    -python script2.py $< > $@

%$(UNCOMP) : %$(COMP)
    @# Ignore decompression failure
    -python uncomp.py $<

$(PACKAGE)/.htaccess : .htaccess | $(PACKAGE)
    cp .htaccess $(PACKAGE)/

$(PACKAGE) : *.zip
    rm -rf $(PACKAGE)/
    unzip *.zip -d $(PACKAGE)/
    make uncomp

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -rf $(PACKAGE)/
```